# Performance doesn't improve with Ray working on 4-CPU-cores

Tags: python-3.x, performance, concurrency, parallel-processing, ray

I'm trying to rerun the **[ray](/questions/tagged/ray)** tutorial on my machine, but I'm failing to reproduce the performance improvements as shown in the tutorial.

What could be the reason for it? I have tried looking for solutions but still not able to understand.

[image: performance comparison with & without ray]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q** : ***What** could be the reason for it?*

### <sub>... an extremely low ( almost Zero ) **`[PARALLEL]`** code-execution **portion**
[image]

When add-on overheads are added to the revised-Amdahl, ***"negative"*** **speedup << 1** ( *slowdowns* ) become obvious</sub>
The [Amdahl's Law](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3), defines the rationale WHY, next comes the WHAT :

**First:**
never start "benchmarking" without having correctly isolated the **SuT** - the **S**ystem-**u**nder-**T**est, here being the ***distributed***-form of a **computation**.

Here, the **`start = time.time()`** being ***" in front of "*** the `import ray` statement seems to be rather a provocative test of the readers' concentration on subject, definitely not a sign of a properly engineered use-case test-design - you knowingly take into the measured time also all the disk-I/O latency + data-transfers from disk into the python session, TimeDOMAIN costs of syntax-checks of the imported module, yes - interpretation ( not having the same conditions in the second test )

**Next:**
After shaving-off the costs of `import`, one may start to compare *"apples to apples"*:

```
...
#----------------------------------------- APPLES-TO-APPLES ( STILL AWFULLY NAIVE )
start   = time.time()
futures = [ f(i) for i in range(4) ]
print( time.time() - start )
print( 60*"_" + " pure-[SERIAL] python execution" )
#----------------------------------------- ORANGES
start   = time.time()
import ray                               # costs of initial import
ray.init( num_cpus = 4 )                 # costs of parametrisation
@ray.remote                              # costs of decorated def(s)
def f( x ):
    return x * x
print( time.time() - start )
print( 60*"_" + " ray add-on overheads" )
#----------------------------------------- APPLES-TO-APPLES ( STILL AWFULLY NAIVE )
start   = time.time()
futures = [ f.remote(i) for i in range(4) ]
print( time.time() - start )
print( 60*"_" + " ray.remote-decorated python execution" )
```

---

### Next comes the scaling :

For **miniature scales of use**, like building all the artillery of parallel/distributed code-execution **for just -4- calls**, the measurements are possible, yet skewed by many hardware-related and software-related tricks ( memory allocations and cache side-effects being most often the performance blockers, once the SuT has been well crafted not to overshadow these next typical HPC core troubles ).

```
>>> def f( x ):
...     return x * x
...
>>> dis.dis( f )
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Having **"low density" of computing** ( here taking just one **`MUL x, x`** in a straight `RET` ) will never justify all the initial setup-costs and all the per-call add-on overhead-costs, that matter in small computing-density cases, not so in complex and CPU-intensive HPC computing tasks ( for which the [Amdahl's Law](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) says,where are the principal limits for achievable speedups stay ).

The next snippet will show the average per-call costs of f.remote()-calls, spread over 4-CPU `ray.remote`-processing paths, compared with a plain, monopolistic GIL-stepped mode of processing ( for details on [min, Avg, MAX, StDev] see other benchmarking posts )

```
#----------------------------------------- APPLES-TO-APPLES scaled ( STILL NAIVE )
test_4N = 1E6                            # 1E6, 1E9, ... larger values may throw exception due to a poor ( not well fused ) range()-iterator construction, workarounds possible
start   = time.time()
futures = [ f.remote(i) for i in range( int( test_4N ) ) ]
print( ( time.time() - start ) /             test_4N )
print( 60*"_" + " ray.remote-decorated python execution per one call" )
#----------------------------------------- APPLES-TO-APPLES scaled ( STILL NAIVE )
start   = time.time()
futures = [ f(i) for i in range( int( test_4N ) ) ]
print( time.time() - start /          test_4N )
print( 60*"_" + " pure-[SERIAL] python execution" )
```

---

> Bonus part
> ### **Smoke-on :** ###
> If indeed interested in burning some more fuel to make some sense of how the intensive computing may benefit from a just-**`[CONCURRENT]`**, True-**`[PARALLEL]`**  or even **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)** try to add more CPU-intensive computing, some remarkable RAM memory allocations, go well beyond the CPU core's L3-cache sizes, pass larger BLOB-s between processes in parameters and result(s)' transfers, live near if not slightly beyond the O/S's efficient process-switching and RAM-swapping, simply go closer towards the real-life computing problems, where latency and resulting performance indeed matters :

```
import numpy as np
@ray.remote
def bigSmoke( voidPar = -1 ):
    #                                +------------- this has to compute a lot
    #      +-------------------------|------------- this has to allocate quite some RAM ~ 130 MB for 100 x str( (2**18)! )
    #      |                         |                 + has to spend add-on overhead costs
    #      |                         |                          for process-to-process result(s) ~ 1.3 MB  for  (2**18)!
    #      |                         |                          SER/DES-transformations & transfer costs
    #      |    +--------------------|------------- this has to allocate quite some RAM ~ 1.3 MB for (2**18)!
    #      |    |                    |           +- this set with care, soon O/S swapping may occur above physical RAM sizes
    return [ str( np.math.factorial( i )     #   |              and immense degradation of the otherwise CPU-processing appears then
                                 for i in int( 1E2 ) * ( 2**18, )
                  )
             ][-1] # <----------------------------- this reduces the amount of SER/DES-transformations & process-2-process transfer costs

...
#----------------------------------------- APPLES-TO-APPLES scaled + computing
test_4N = 1E1                            # be cautious here, may start from 1E0, 1E1, 1E2, 1E3 ...
start   = time.time()
futures = [ bigSmoke.remote(i) for i in range( int( test_4N ) ) ]
print( ( time.time() - start ) /                    test_4N )
print( 60*"_" + " ray.remote-decorated set of numpy.math.factorial( 2**18 ) per one call" )
#----------------------------------------- APPLES-TO-APPLES scaled + computing
start   = time.time()
futures = [ bigSmoke(i) for i in range( int( test_4N ) ) ]
print( ( time.time() - start ) /             test_4N )
print( 60*"_" + " pure-[SERIAL] python execution of a set of numpy.math.factorial( 2**18 ) per one call" )
```

Anyway, be warned that premature optimisation efforts are prone to mislead one's focus, so feel free to read performance-tuning stories so often presented here, in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Multiprocessing creates time overhead - I think the base function here is so quick that the overhead takes the majority of the time. Does the tutorial really use a simple integer as input ? If you use a large array as input you should see an improvement.

Comment: I tried using (8, 8) array as well but that didn't make any difference

Comment: **With all due respect**, an 8-by-8 array of float64 is nothing, it fits even into a few CPU-core registers, **today *"large"* goes way above a few [GB]** ( not mentioning anything less than that for a reasonable testing of a processing performance and an efficiency of a problem algorithmisation )

Comment: how can they show improvements with just looping over a number (4) in the tutorial...I was just following them shouldn't I see the same as shown there..?